# VS 2013 Directx project Vertex shader file missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, directx-11, hlsl, vertex-shader

This is my first experience with shaders, I am following a tutorial for directx programming and I have two shader files included in my project with .vs and .ps file types. I am unsure if these file types are recognized as the file types for hlsl in visual studios have .hlsl at the end. Is there a way to get these file types recognized, if not how would I change my code below to include the different filetype? My code compiles, it just returns my error message saying color.vs missing.

Under the initialization function for my colorshaderclass.cpp the returns function call is as follows:

```
result = InitializeShader(device, hwnd, L"../Engine/color.hlsl", L"../Engine/color.ps");
```

The initializeShader function itself is defined as follows:

```
bool ColorShaderClass::InitializeShader(ID3D11Device* device, HWND hwnd, WCHAR* vsFilename, WCHAR* psFilename)
{
HRESULT result;
ID3D10Blob* errorMessage;
ID3D10Blob* vertexShaderBuffer;
ID3D10Blob* pixelShaderBuffer;
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC polygonLayout[2];
unsigned int numElements;
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC matrixBufferDesc;

//initializ the pointers this function will use to null
errorMessage = 0;
vertexShaderBuffer = 0;
pixelShaderBuffer = 0;

//compile vertex shader code
result = D3DX11CompileFromFile(vsFilename, NULL, NULL, "ColorVertexShader", "vs_5_0", D3D10_SHADER_ENABLE_STRICTNESS, 0, NULL,
    &vertexShaderBuffer, &errorMessage, NULL);

if (FAILED(result))
{
    //if the shader failed to compile it should have written something to error message
    if (errorMessage)
    {
        OutputShaderErrorMessage(errorMessage, hwnd, vsFilename);
    }
    //if there was nothing in error message then it couldnt find shader file
    else
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, vsFilename, L"Missing Shader File", MB_OK);
    }

    return false;
}

//compile pixel shader code
if (FAILED(result))
{
    if (errorMessage)
    {
        OutputShaderErrorMessage(errorMessage, hwnd, psFilename);
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, psFilename, L"Missing Shader File", MB_OK);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm not sure if this is a settings issue or if I need to change the filetype or if I need to include headers (tried this option though and VS tried to debug the hlsl file using c++ syntax).

Comment: What specifically is the value you are getting back as ``result``?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any `#include` statements in your shader? As noted in the docs on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476261.aspx), if you provide a pInclude handler of 'NULL' then any `#include` statement will fail.

Also, you do not need to be using the deprecated D3DX11 library from the legacy DirectX SDK here particularly since you have the VS 2013 toolset. You can use `D3DCompileFromFile` directly and should use `D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE` for the pInclude handler. See [HLSL FXC and D3DCompile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx) as well as [Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx).

```
result = D3DCompileFromFile(vsFilename, nullptr,
    D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE , "ColorVertexShader", "vs_5_0",
    D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS, 0, &vertexShaderBuffer, &errorMessage );
```

You may want to review [this tutorial](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20custom%20shaders) for some hints on creating and using your own shaders, particularly if you want to use Visual Studio to build them at compile time into .cso which avoids the need to use `D3DCompileFromFile` at all at runtime.

Comment: I don't have any include statements. Changing the pInclude handler seems to have gotten VS to find the file, however it is doing the same thing as before where it is debugging the file as if it were c++ code. As I was asking before is this due to the fact that they should be different filetypes than .vs and .ps? Will changing these to .cso get it recognized as hlsl?

Comment: The filename extension is irrelevant if you are directly compiling it with a function. The filename extensions ``.hlsl`` and ``.fx`` are recognized by Visual Studio 2012+ and built with FXC.EXE, but that's a build-time and not runtime. A ``.cso`` is a pre-compiled shader and you use that data directly with the ``Create*Shader`` functions.

Answer (score 0):

As Chuck has mentioned, you're using a deprecated API, and you also need to be sure that shader files are compiled to .cso, because that is what it is to be read by your application. VS 2013 automatically compiles .hlsl files into .cso when you compile your .cpp files, so that shouldn't be a problem. Just assume that .cso files are there when you write the LoadShaderFile function. Example extracted from [this excellent tutorial](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=112-4-5), under the section "Using shaders":

```
#include <fstream>

// this function loads a file into an Array^
Array<byte>^ LoadShaderFile(std::string File)
{
    Array<byte>^ FileData = nullptr;

    // open the file
    std::ifstream VertexFile(File, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    // if open was successful
    if(VertexFile.is_open())
    {
        // find the length of the file
        int Length = (int)VertexFile.tellg();

        // collect the file data
        FileData = ref new Array<byte>(Length);
        VertexFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        VertexFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(FileData->Data), Length);
        VertexFile.close();
    }

    return FileData;
}

//... And this is the call and use.
Array<byte>^ VSFile = LoadShaderFile("VertexShader.cso");
device->CreateVertexShader(VSFile->Data, VSFile->Length, nullptr, &vertexshader);
```